# What does Version mean in the .desktop file?

Tags: application-development

While submitting an application to the Ubuntu Touch store, I got the following error message.

```
"desktop_Version (Cliffhanger)": {
     "text": "'0.3' does not match freedesktop.org version '1.0'"
}
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the .desktop file, there is a line which starts with "*Version=*". This field allows you to specify the version of the .desktop file specification by freedesktop.org. It is a common mistake to specify your application version here.

This field is optional and doesn't need to be included in your desktop. But if you do include it, make sure to set it to the currently supported .desktop file specification version. At the time of answering this question, it is 1.0.